# Where is the instance of the Pillow Image class being created after calling open() method?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to understand how `Image.open()` works in Pillow module. I want to know the place where the instance of the `Image class` is being created before returning it in the `open()` method.

Comment: You can add some code example.

Comment: Here's some [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that should help.

Comment: @martineau if it is possible, can you point me the exact place where we are being redirected to the object creation method after we call open() method? I watched trough the code multiple times and didn`t get it where this happens.
Thank you for your previous answer.

Comment: @LiuXiMin Thank you, I know that. The main reason I'm asking this question is because I dont clearly understand code in Pillow Image module. I can poste some code, but due to my lack of understanding, I'll probably post too much unnecessary code or miss something very important.

Comment: It's the statement `im = factory(fp, filename)` in the function `_open_core()` nested inside the `open()` function in the [source code](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/Image.html#open). The variable `factory` is the image file factory method of one of the image file plugins registered via the [`PIL.Image.register_open()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.register_open) function.

Comment: @martineau thank you very much! Thats exactly what I wanted to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple:
the first thing that you make wen use Pillow is to instantiate the class.

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image() #Here we instantiate the class Image.
```

Now you can open the image.

```
img = image.open('some_img.jpg')
```

if you want a Numpy array you can simple use:

```
img_array = np.array(img)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. As soon as I type `image = Image()` it throws an exception:
`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.`
Probably, thats because of the `Image` being a python file `Image.py` like so:
`from CONTAINER import FILE`. So I can access the class if I do:
`image = Image.Image()`, but thats not the case I'm asking about. The thing I wanna know is how do we create instance of `Image class` by calling `open()` method which is out of the `Image class` scope. Where is the place where that instance is created before returning it in `open()` method?

Comment: I believe you should inherit the Image class object. `class MyImage(Image):  def __init__(self,**args,**kwargs):` so you will have a new object that has the same methods as Image class.